# Footer isn't showing fully in mobile view

Tags: html, css, flexbox

really don't know what the problem is, so I count on your support with this one. So when Im trying to view my website on any mobile device with 100% zoom footer isn't showing at all, but If you zoom for 50% the footer is showing. Below you can see some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

and this is my code:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container fter">
        <div class="footerLogo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="socialsFooter">
            <ul class="socialsList">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="fterCredits">
            <h4>© 2016 <a href="#"> MULITIX THEME</a> BY THEMEFORCES. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

```
footer {
  padding: 140px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px -5px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.6);
}

.fter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footerLogo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 44px;
}

.socialsFooter {
  border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  padding: 23px 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: 44px;
}

ul.socialsList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 440px;
}

ul.socialsList a {
  color: #808080;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  line-height: 27px;
  transition: .3s;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.socialsList a:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fterCredits {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fterCredits h4 {
  color: #808080;
  font-family: "Roboto-Light", sans-serif;
}

.fterCredits a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto-Light", sans-serif;
}
```

you can see the full problem here:
https://rissutei4.github.io/LianCreativeAgency/

Comment: so, how would it fit all the content in the height of the screen if the content doesn't fit in the height of the screen?

Comment: What is the behavior you expect?

Comment: @GalAbra I want footer to fully show up in 100%, like on the first screenshot

Comment: @GarrGodfrey what do you mean?

Comment: actually,  your problem is the iPad emulator doesn't fit within your browser window.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey is it really the problem with the browser window? Because I have checked more than 5 times and I don't really think the problem is with it

Comment: I mean, yes, the aspect ratio is completely different. You can only see part of the emulated iPad screen because that's all that fits on your computer screen. That's why you need to scale it down to see what it would look like on an iPad

Comment: The iPad emulation at 100% is 1024 pixels high, the section shown is only 812 pixels high. More than 200 pixels are cut off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your site is perfectly responsive, the issue is from chrome dev tools.**

You can turn on ruler option here:

[image: menu for setting ruler]

After turning that on, you can see that for 50% size, the horizontal resolution shown is smaller than 1024, which means that chrome cuts a part off the screen.

[image: 100% sized chrome dev tools]

With size 50%, you can see that the whole screen will be shown:
[image: 50% sized chrome dev tools]

Comment: thanks a lot! I thought something was wrong